# Exporting Lists from Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, export, table, list

I am using code from the emapr lab to learn to use LandTrendr to get mean NDVI values per year for a geometry. I am trying to export the generated list from earth engine to Drive.  The list only contains Year, Original NDVI and Fitted NDVI values.  The error I am getting is- "Unknown element type provided: object. Expected:  ee.Image, ee.ImageCollection, ee.FeatureCollection or ee.Element."  How can I convert a list in order to export it to drive as a csv?

A [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/66f7f81f4092011fd5a7415c4829dd84) to the code I am using.

The end bit of my code:

```
var yearSummary = getSummary(yearBandStack, aoi, summaryScale).toArray();
var rawSummary = getSummary(rawBandStack, aoi, summaryScale).toArray();
var fitSummary = getSummary(fitBandStack, aoi, summaryScale).toArray();
var chartArray = ee.Array.cat([yearSummary, rawSummary, fitSummary], 1).getInfo();
chartArray = [['Year', 'Original', 'Fitted']].concat(chartArray);

print(chartArray)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: chartArray,
  folder: 'Test_Folder',
  description:'test_chartArray',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 7):

In no way the best solution to this as it will require some formatting of the csv after download.  But it was the quickest I could do without having to spend way too much time re-writing all your code.

**When you want to export to a csv, what you export is the properties of a feature collection.**

So I made a null geometry feature collection containing your arrays and then exported that.

```
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(chartArray
                        .map(function(element){
                        return ee.Feature(null,{prop:element})}))


print(featureCollection)

//Export.table.toDrive(ee.Element(chartArray));
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollection,
  folder: 'Test_Folder',
  description:'test_chartArray',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```